# unable to read last line, using getline()

Tags: c++, string, std

I have to read the test cast as follows.

```
3
ababa
abc
babac
```

c++ code to read the above input.

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--){
        string s;
        getline(cin,s);
        cin.clear();
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

but the output I'm getting is

```
ababa
abc
```

can you help me how to read the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
cin >> t;
```

the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you used to end that input is left in the input buffer as a newline. This newline will be read by the first call to `getline` as an "empty" line.

A simple solution is to [*ignore*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the remaining of the input after getting the input for `t`:

```
cin >> t;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

---

I also recommend that you use the status of the stream as part of the loop condition:

```
string s;
while (t-- && getline(cin, s))
{
    cout << s << '\n';
}
```

This way you won't be attempting to read beyond the end of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `cin >> s;` unless there are multiple words in a string

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    while (t--) {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To read the last line, you can use `cin>>s;` to read the string instead of

````
getline(cin,s);
cin.clear();```
````